# jQuery.get callback not called in IE6

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-6, callback

I have some Javascript code containing calls to jQuery.get().  I'm passing a callback to receive the response from the server.

In Firefox 3.5 (Windows and Linux) and IE8, the callback is called reliably.  In IE6, it's never called.

I've tried jQuery 1.3 and 1.4 -- same result.

Is there some setting in IE6 that could cause such a problem?  I've tried IE6 from a couple of different machines, same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Can you confirm that in IE6 the server talk is taking place and that the data is being received, if not then its not a callback issue but and XmlHttpRequest issue.

Also try setting the dataType attribute in the ajax call to whatever your fetching, so for instances if your fetching an xml document then do

```
$(function() {
        $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "some.xml",
                dataType: "xml", //<<<<<<<<
                success: function(xmlData)
                {
                        alert('Fetch')
                }
        });
});
```

As iv'e heard that it has caused some issues in the past.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many things, without success.  Wireshark tells me that the server is sending 
the requested data back to the browser.

So now I detect IE6 and redirect to a page that says "please upgrade your browser".

That's not ideal, because IE6 is still the default browser on Windows XP.  However, 
our target audience is software developers, and they shouldn't be bothered too much 
by having to upgrade.

Answer (score -2):

Horse die - come down. I would recommend to stop supporting IE6. As it do Google Gmail, YouTube, Facebook and Digg. The share of IE6 is already negligible.
P.S.> Sorry for my english.

Comment: Paul may well have a very good reason to support IE6 - some corporations still have all their users on IE6. According to the few browser stats I just looked at IE6 has a comparable user base as Chrome or Safari - between 5% and 10% - far from negligible.

Comment: Also I would like to extend that comment with another reason to support IE, IE6 is stil the default browser in Windows Xp  and the fact that a good 50/60% of businesses still use Windows Xp and the proxy settings etc to control there users, this would just be one more reason to support IE6